# How to limit datetime-local input field to specific dates and time for appointments?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, datetime, datetimepicker

I am using datetime-local input field to give the user the posibility to pick a date and time for his appointment....I need to restrict date to start only from today date and from 8:00 to 16:00 everyday...In addition to showing only some of the remaining dates for booking.

in other words:

- Every day the user will be able to pick just time between 8:00 and
  16:00.
- Example this week the only days available are 21-09-2021, 23-09-2021 and 24-09.2021.

How to do that using datetime-local picker or any other datetime picker?

```
<input id="party" type="datetime-local" name="partydate" value="2017-06-01T08:30">
```

Comment: i think it's easier just to use plugins like [https://xdsoft.net/jqplugins/datetimepicker/#allowTimes](https://xdsoft.net/jqplugins/datetimepicker/#allowTimes)

Comment: Either date, datetime-local, or time only support `min` and `max` restrictions.  HTML doesn't support excluding specific dates or times within a range.  What you want to make requires JavaScript.  You can make it on your own or use a plugin like what Fatima suggested.

Comment: Can you give me a hint please, because I tried to use what in the docs but it doesn't work